# How in the world set focus programmatically in Angular 16?

Tags: angular16

I have this code in the component

```
 @ViewChild('autocomplete', { static: false }) autocomplete: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement> = {} as ElementRef;

mostrarModalLocalizacao(){

    this.autocomplete.nativeElement.focus()

    this.visivel = true;

  }
```

my template is something like this:

```
<input #autocomplete>
```

How to make my code work. I am getting undefined nativeElement when this function is run, mostrarModalLocalizacao.

Answer (score 0):

Your function mostrarModalLocalizacao is probably being called before the view is initialized, which means autocomplete hasn't been populated yet, and this.autocomplete.nativeElement is undefined.

Alternatively, you could use the ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook to ensure your view child is available:

```
import { AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

// ...

export class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('autocomplete', { static: false }) autocomplete: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement> = {} as ElementRef;
  
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // this.autocomplete is available here
  }
  
  mostrarModalLocalizacao() {
    if (this.autocomplete && this.autocomplete.nativeElement) {
      this.autocomplete.nativeElement.focus();
      this.visivel = true;
    }
  }
}
```